How can I use templates effectively?
I've been writing some C++ code recently. I've encountered a situation in which a template class would be perfect for me, but I'm not sure about defining its members in .cpp file. I want to precise that I know about certain problems happening to template classes divided into header and source files, but I have no idea how can I implement any template classes in real projects, while keeping my code organized.
Consider a vector class:
vector.h
template <typename T>
class Vector {
    ...
    public:
        Vector();
    ...
};

vector.cpp
#include "vector.h"

template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector() {
    //body
}

Of course, defining an object in main.cpp:
#include "vector.h"

int main() {
    Vector<int> v();
}

causes the compilator to produce an error:
main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `Vector<int>::Vector()

How do people deal with such errors?
I've read that explicit declaration of class type, e.g. Vector<int> solves the issue, but I feel like I don't understand something and that it's kinda the opposite of this whole template idea.

Templates should generally be implemented in the header file, not in cpp. See: Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?.

Why can templates only be implemented in the header file? explains both best practices and alternatives if you must have your implementation in another file.
